# jupyter notebook: return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, cloud, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04

Hi I want to run the jupyter notebook on the cloud Ubuntu server(16.04).
  and the server IP is 213.138.10.176 (just example), and port is 22011
I have installed jupyter, and python 2.07, and edited the jupyter_notebook_config.py as following:

```
   c.NotebookApp.ip = '213.138.10.176'
   c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
   c.NotebookApp.port = 22011
```

But after I saved it, and run jupyter notebook command on the Ubuntn server.
there is error:

```
     File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1296, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1120, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 126, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 182, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I don't use this, I use another way but I need to set every time. If you want, I can send you the link.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015450/issue-installing-jupyter-on-arch/48052652#48052652 using --ip=127.0.0.1 seem to work