# Issue installing Jupyter on Arch

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to get a [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) notebook up and running on Arch. I have tried installying the `jupyter` package. I also tried following the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Jupyter) and installed `jupyter-notebook` and `jupyter-nbconvert` and `python-ipywidgets`. Lastly, I tried using [the `pip` instructions](https://jupyter.org/install.html). All three of which fail and give:

```
➜  ~ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1368, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1188, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 142, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 197, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

It seems that the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406257/jupyter-notebook-return-getattrself-sock-nameargs-socket-error-errno-99) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189532/unable-to-open-jupyter-notebook) related to this involve a different error with `sock.bind`. I am not sure if the issue is related or not. Any guidance on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: try passing the --ip=127.0.0.1 we may try to bind to `localhost` which arch does not like. This is weird though.

Comment: @Matt Thanks that worked! If you want to post as answer feel free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `socket.bind()` usually you can pass it either a hostname or an ip. In particular as we oly listen on the local loopback address we can pass either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` (for ip v4) or `::1` for ip v6.

In *theory* both would be identical, but in practice there are number of systems where one (or the other) is problematic. It can be firewall, and antivirus seeing this binding as suspicious, or strange network configurations. While you probably still should investigate why `socket.bind()`  refuses `localhost` (in your case), you can configure the jupyter notebook server to bind directly to 127.0.0.1 by using either : `jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1`, or change the configuration of jupyter notebook server with the equivalent long form option `c.NotebookApp.ip='127.0.0.1'`.

Also if his is widespread on Arch (and install via the arch repo) I would suggest contacting the arch package maintainer to have a custom patch that switch the default value to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: There might be something wrong with my network config. I was trying to get my schools internet to work with Arch and apparently there are a lot of issues. I could have messed something up. Currently I see no other comments on the package. Thanks again.